# What is a better way to parse a raw date that is a string of numbers in Java?

Tags: java

Here is my raw date: "20231110"

Here is my code solution:

```
    private String handleRawSwiftDateValue(String rawDateValue) {
    // year = 0,4 - month 4,6 - day - 6,lastIndex
    return new StringBuilder().append(rawDateValue.substring(0, 4))
            .append("-").append(rawDateValue.substring(4, 6))
            .append("-").append(rawDateValue.substring(6)).toString();
}
```

It produces the LocalDate format that I need 2023-11-10.

I have tried this to no avail:

```
LocaDate fromString = LocalDate.parse("20231110"); //<- the default format is what I need which is ISO_LOCAL_DATE
```

This above code throws an exception.

I think my solution is ok (it works), but I am almost sure there is a better way, anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Well the question is what do you need it for? Are you fine with just a String representation of your local date? or do you need the LocalDate object?

Comment: If you need to parse it into LocalDate, you need to pass a DateTimeFormatter to specify the pattern of LocalDate it should parse

Comment: Entity property type of LocalDate, so this above method is called by LocalDate.parse()

Comment: Yes I did that already, still fails

Comment: unless I am being a total idiot, making a silly mistake but I did do this line here
LocalDate.parse("20231110", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
That throws an exception

Comment: 20231110 is not yyyy-MM-dd. thats the basic ISO date yyyyMMdd.

Comment: Right, so my method handleRawSwiftDateValue gives me the right format, but I don't want to use my method to format the raw String date of "20231110"

Comment: You have to tell the `LocalDate.parse()` method the format it is getting, otherwise it will (try to) use `"uuuu-MM-dd"`… That can be done by providing a `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: LocalDate.parse has a default formatter of ISO_LOCAL_DATE which is yyyy-MM-dd
So passing in the formatter is not working

Comment: As a side note, instead of `.append(rawDateValue.substring(0, 4))` you can use `.append(rawDateValue, 0, 4)`, without creating an intermediate string. This might come handy for other tasks…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` to parse strings instead of getting substrings.

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter rawFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
private static final DateTimeFormatter outputFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

private String handleRawSwiftDateValue(String rawDateValue) {
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(rawDateValue, rawFormat);
    return localDate.format(outputFormat);
}
```

Or more simply use [the built-in formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#BASIC_ISO_DATE):

```
String output = 
    LocalDate
    .parse( "20231110" , DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE ) 
    .toString() ;
```

Comment: You don't need to define the `DateTimeFormatter outputFormat`, just take the prebuilt one `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE`. Otherwise, this is the way to go…

Comment: I think you have it, my mistake is I need to handle the raw format first, I was thinking I could pass in the raw string and LocalDate would take care of it

Comment: Yes so basically `return localDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);`

Comment: Also this is LocalDate.parse source

  public static LocalDate parse(CharSequence text) {
        return parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
    }

Comment: There is no need for *any* format calls.  `return localDate.toString();` will produce a yyyy-mm-dd string.

Comment: Actually this works for me, 
  LocalDate  date = LocalDate.parse("20231110", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"));

Which gives me the default format of ISO_LOCAL_DATE

My entity property wants local date anyway,
It looks like I was using the wrong format, thats it

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments/suggestions!